# SOAP - load local WSDL file

Tags: php, xml, soap, wsdl

How to load a local WSDL file into `SoapClient`?

```
$wsdl = __DIR__.'/wsdl.wsdl';
$this->client = new SoapClient($wsdl);

$xsd = __DIR__.'/wsdl/xsd/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd';
```

> PHP Fatal error:  SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Could not find any usable
>   binding services in WSDL.

relative path to XSD file from WSDL file: `./xsd/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd`

## WSDL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" >
    <wsdl:types>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: Have you tried to set the soap version in the second paramter for the soap client? Just add an array as second parameter: `new SoapClient($wsdl, [ 'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1 ]);`. When SOAP_1_1 does not work also try SOAP_1_2. Perhaps your issue is solved with this already.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your WSDL file,

```
<soap:binding style="document" transport="https://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/https"/>
```

should be

```
<soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
```

Comment: HTTPS everywhere FTW :)